# Trying to execute a query after session_start for logged in user

Tags: php, mysql

So Im a total noob to PHP.

I have a php document that begins with session_start(); after that I proceed to run a query. something like that

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname   = "";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
        $sql = "SELECT id,username, date 
        FROM calendar WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['uid']['username'] ."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $json_array = array();
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
               {
                    $json_array[] = [
    $row['id'],
    $row['username'],
    $row['date']
    $TotalTime
    ];
     }
               echo json_encode($json_array); 
    ?>
```

the query runs if i dont include session_start(); but it fails to run if I include  session_start(); at the beginning. Im sure Im missing some transition here. I need to get session of logged in user for my query to work properly.

When I add at the bottom

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";  
?>
```

I get this. I belive its from another table called "users".

```
[]
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(34)
  ["uid"]=>
  string(8) "bostin21"
  ["email"]=>
  string(18) "emaill123@gmail.com"
  ["user"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: Do you have `uid.username` in session? Maybe it's missing. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` after session_start

Comment: I just inserted that and get Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in /post_fc.php on line 10.
And just to add my query runs if i dont include session_start(); at top of document. But if i dont include session_start than I cant get $_SESSION['uid']

Comment: make a var_dump($_SESSION); to see what os stiored in your session

Comment: I edited my original question with full code and var_dump

Answer (score 0):

please make sure if you have uid.username in your sesssion

```
$_SESSION['uid']['username']
```

please give your full source for us

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it lol.

my value was just a string and not defined yet. I added

```
$uid1 = $_SESSION['uid'];
```

and added that to my query